# How to convert edge selection to outer edges only?

Tags: selection-tools, edges

I have a selection of edges. I would like to convert my selection to the outer edges only. How do I do this automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Ensure you are in edge selection mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> > *Edges*.
2. Then in the 3D view header *Select* > *Select Boundary Loop*

Alternatively you could (for such a simple selection) just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the first edge, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the second edge.

Comment: Or even faster, Ctrl Alt RMB on the edge ring.

Comment: this helped me select boundaries of comples shapes, where I wanted to mark seams for unwrapping.